# How can I stop the incoming message tone in Symbian

Tags: symbian

I there anyway in Symbian to stop the incoming message tone after it starts playing ?

I tried to use the following code to stop the sound after it starts, but it didn't work:

```
User::ResetInactivityTime();
```

I'm using Symbian C++
Targeting Symbian S60 5th Ed, Symbian^3 and Symbian Anna

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need the MultimediaDD capability, which you will never, ever get (legally)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to catch some of your own specific messages not all user messages.

AFAIK there is no easy solution. You could try to listen the sockets and catch your message before it arrives to the Inbox.

Comment: your assumption is right, but I don't care to stop the sound immediately when the message arrives, 2 seconds of default tone won't cause me a problem, that is why I tried to reset the user activity in vain, do you have any idea how to imitate user activity to stop the sound, and then I start playing mine ?